# Coalesced memory access and global memory load/store efficiency with complex arithmetics in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I'm profiling the following CUDA kernel

```
__global__ void fftshift_2D(double2 *data, int N1, int N2)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    int j = threadIdx.y + blockDim.y * blockIdx.y;

    if (i < N1 && j < N2) {
        double a = pow(-1.0, (i+j)&1);

        data[j*blockDim.x*gridDim.x+i].x *= a;
        data[j*blockDim.x*gridDim.x+i].y *= a;
    }
 }
```

which basically multiplies a 2D double precision complex data matrix by a scalar double precision variable.

As it can be seen, I'm performing a coalesced global memory access and I want to verify this by the NVIDIA Visual Profiler by inspecting the global memory load and store efficiencies. Surprisingly, such efficiencies turn out to be both exactly 50%, far from the expected 100% for coalesced memory access. Is this related to the interlaced storage of real and imaginary parts for complex numbers? If so, is there any trick I could exploit to restore a 100% efficiency?

Thank you in advance.

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

```
BLOCK_SIZE_x=16
BLOCK_SIZE_y=16

dim3 dimBlock2(BLOCK_SIZE_x,BLOCK_SIZE_y);
dim3 dimGrid2(N2/BLOCK_SIZE_x + (N2%BLOCK_SIZE_x == 0 ? 0:1),N1/BLOCK_SIZE_y + (N1%BLOCK_SIZE_y == 0 ? 0:1));
```

N1 and N2 can be arbitrary even numbers.

The card is an NVIDIA GT 540M.

Comment: More info needed. N1=? N2=? blockDim=? gridDim=? `j*blockDim.x*gridDim.x+i` looks odd. Could it be something like `j*N1+i`?

Comment: @talonmies I have added additional information in my revised post.

Comment: @EricShiyinKang I have added additional information in my revised post. I believe that the data indexing is fine.

Comment: @JackOLantern: Is this a Fermi or Kepler GPU?

Comment: @talonmies Provided in the revised post.

Comment: @JackOLantern: I see others have already given you a solution, but keep in mind that your indexing scheme is actually only ok because you are using an 8 byte floating point type. If you do a single precision version, you will have to change the code, otherwise you will be back to 50% coalesced access, albeit for a different reason.

Comment: @talonmies You are definitely right. I will take care of that in case I will be switching to single precision. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [this NVIDIA Blog Post about efficiency of various memory access patterns](http://developer.nvidia.com/node/582497). You're hitting Strided Memory Access problem.

Since each component is used independently you could treat your `double2` array as a plain normal `double` array instead (just like [Robert Crovella suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14247543/56875%29)).

```
__global__ void fftshift_2D(double *data, int N1, int N2)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    int j = threadIdx.y + blockDim.y * blockIdx.y;

    if (i < N1 * 2 && j < N2) {
        double a = pow(-1.0, (i / 2 + j)&1);
        data[j*blockDim.x*gridDim.x+i] *= a;
    }
}
```

But if you ever need to access both x & y components in a single thread you could try:

Using 2 separate arrays. One with x component one with y component. Like that:

```
__global__ void fftshift_2D(double *dataX, double *dataY, int N1, int N2)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    int j = threadIdx.y + blockDim.y * blockIdx.y;

    if (i < N1 && j < N2) {
        double a = pow(-1.0, (i+j)&1);

        dataX[j*blockDim.x*gridDim.x+i] *= a;
        dataY[j*blockDim.x*gridDim.x+i] *= a;
    }
}
```

Or leaving the data layout as is but loading it with no stride into shared memory and reshuffling it from shared memory. That would look more or less like that:

```
__global__ void fftshift_2D(double2 *data, int N1, int N2)
{
    __shared__ double buff[BLOCK_SIZE*2];
    double2 *buff2 = (double2 *) buff;
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    int j = threadIdx.y + blockDim.y * blockIdx.y;
    double ptr = (double *) &data[j*blockDim.x*gridDim.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x];

    // TODO add guarding with N1 & N2
    buff[threadIdx.x] = ptr[threadIdx.x];
    buff[blockDim.x + threadIdx.x] = ptr[blockDim.x + threadIdx.x];
    __syncthreads();

    double a = pow(-1.0, (i+j)&1);
    buff2[threadIdx.x].x *= a 
    buff2[threadIdx.x].y *= a 

    __syncthreads();
    ptr[threadIdx.x] = buff[threadIdx.x];
    ptr[blockDim.x + threadIdx.x] = buff[blockDim.x + threadIdx.x];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the different options provided. Your first solution worked just fine from a semantic point of view. It exploits the fact that the multiplication is performed with a real (not complex) variable. With respect to this, the third solution would be useful for a complex scaling constant. The second solution would force rearranging the data (I do not know how worth it would be).

Comment: As a downside, the first solution appears to be slower than the code in my original post, notwithstanding the full 100% global memory load/store efficiencies. Do you have an explanation for that? Thanks.

Comment: Your comment got me thinking. According to this blog post https://developer.nvidia.com/content/how-access-global-memory-efficiently-cuda-cc-kernels "Compute capability 1.2 and higher hardware can coalesce accesses that fall into aligned segments (32, 64, or 128 byte segments on CC 1.2/1.3, and 128-byte cache lines on CC 2.0 and higher)," So all GPUs should be capable of loading 128bit double2 in one blow without reducing bandwidth...

Comment: A recent discussion with some further comments can be found at the [NVIDIA Forum](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/527302/cuda-programming-and-performance/coalesced-memory-access-and-global-memory-load-store-efficiency-with-complex-arithmetics-in-cuda/).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, since you have an array of structures data storage format, and you are referencing only every other element with the following line:

```
    data[j*blockDim.x*gridDim.x+i].x *= a;
```

then the global load and the global store that occurs as a result, will each only have 50% utilization.  Note that I think the cache should help here, since you're referencing the alternate elements on the following line.  But the load/store efficiency is still 50%.

I believe you could work around this (for this particular example) using some method to recast `*data`:

```
double *mydata = (double *)data;
...
mydata[2*(j*blockDim.x*gridDim.x)+i] *= a;
```

Please note I'm not trying to show exactly how to get the same coverage, just illustrate the idea.  The code above is approximately what is needed, but you will need to tweak the code to make sure all the elements you want to be multiplied are handled correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your idea. Based on that, Przemyslaw Zych has posted a solution I have successfully used for my problem: Now I have 100% global memory load and store efficiencies.